# Array_max spark.sql.function not found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdp, spark-shell

I need to use the function array_max and array_min from the package org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ but both functions are not found?

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
scala>... array_max(col(..))
error: not found: value array_max
```

ps :

1. scala version 2.11.8
2. spark version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292
3. HDP 2.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def array_max(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column`

This `array_max` function is not available in `Spark 2.3` & it is only available from `Spark 2.4` onwards.

For reference please check below git repos.

`Spark 2.3`

- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala

`Spark 2.4`

- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala

Comment: can we find functions that do the same thing in version 2.3 ?

Comment: You can write simple udf - val arrayMax = udf((values: Seq[Int]) => values.max); df.select(arrayMax($"value").as("array_max")).show